# The_excerpt showing before the div

Tags: php, css, wordpress

i've created latest post container, which i'm trying to create in a shortcode, however when i add the excerpt into the div it is not being shown as it would normally. it is being pushed before the div. The test string after the excerpt is being placed the correct place inside in the div. How come the excerpt is being pushed to the top?

```
 if($insta->have_posts()) : 
  while($insta->have_posts()) : 
     $insta->the_post();
   $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'thumbnail-size', true);
    $post_excerpt = the_excerpt();
    $permalink = get_permalink();

     $output = '<div class="betting-item">'
        . '<div class="betting-thumb">'
        . '<a href=" '. $permalink .' ">'
        . '<img class="thumbnail" src="'. $thumb_url[0] .'" alt="0" />" </a>'
        . '</div>'
        . '<div class="betting-description">'
        . '<h6><a href="">Instalocket</a></h6>'
        . '<div class="meta">November 18, 2014 • No Comments</div>'
        . '<div>' . $post_excerpt[0] . ' test</div>'
        . '</div>'
        . '</div>';



  endwhile;
endif;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because `the_excerpt()` will print the except there and then (so before the div), you need to use `get_the_excerpt ()` which will allow you to print it out at a later stage (in the div).

EDIT:
This should work and only print the excerpt on the first loop:

```
if($insta->have_posts()) : 
  $count = 0;
  while($insta->have_posts()) : 
     $insta->the_post();
   $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'thumbnail-size', true);
    if($count == 0) 
    {
        $post_excerpt = the_excerpt();
        $count = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $post_excerpt = '';
    }
    $permalink = get_permalink();
```

Comment: This places the content right however it only prints the first char of the excerpt now?

Comment: @PeterPik try using `$post_except` instead of  `$post_except[0]`. You are specifying to only print the first character. Removing the  `[0]` should fix that

Comment: Thank you thought i needed to specify the first post in the loop.